is this posible to extract coastline or border line from multipolygon geojson but keep them separate
i have multipolygon cities , how to get coastline or border line that not intersect with other cities, and keep separate each cities,
is that possible? there any software or programing method (like python or js) to extract such data?
for example below i want get colourful line only but keep them separate each cities.

here the geojson file https://gist.github.com/bagusindrayana/d42d0806d00fff1e805e733256eb07bf

already have solution here : gis.stackexchange.com/a/479885/241817 using geopandas in python
